# How secure will your code be with obfuscation?

Tags: c++, .net, obfuscation

Using RedGate's Reflector, you may easily get the full source for an application. But to reduce the chances of an algorithm being found out, there are obfuscators to reduce this likelihood.

My questions are:

- How effective are obfuscators?
- What is safer in terms of hiding your algorithms: C++ without .NET libraries or obfuscated .NET programs.
- Are there any others way to make .NET source code even more secure?

Comment: Why do you think someone would deobfuscate your app?

Comment: In order not to buy it but use it. That is the main reason.

Comment: Obfuscation won't make the hacking of the application process significantly harder, it only makes harder understanding the overall code structure.

Comment: That is important too. I don't want my algorithms to be stealed.

Comment: now I'm curious - have you invented something new, no one have ever seen?

Comment: Well, it's not absolutely new, but I think my program will be usefull and that's why I want to protect it.

Comment: Everything that can be obfuscated automatically, can be deobfuscatef automatically and for there are tools on the marked for each platform to do this. If it is a problem when others see your code, than take a different approach. For instance, Hide sensitive logic behind a web service and let the client app use that srrvice.

Comment: If your algorithms are interesting enough for others, your code will be deobfuscated anyway. No matter what platform or obfuscation tool you use. Don't ship your algorithms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you definitely want to secure something, go for C++, as in the .NET World there is a powerful deobfuscator named de4dot (see here: https://github.com/0xd4d/de4dot) that deobfuscates what most obfuscators on the market produce, event the ones it does not explicitely know.

However, this will only raise the bar, as even in the c++ world, there are powerful tools also (IDA: http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml).

There are other solutions, like mixed code assemblies where you can have the part you want to hide in native code and the rest in managed. see here for more: [Mixed (Native and Managed) Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0w2664k.aspx)

Comment: Thanks to all. I think I will try to use mixed assemblies. By the way is that .net 4.5 feature?

Comment: @seeker: Using unmanaged assemblies has always been a feature of .NET. The link above describes bringing unmanaged assemblies into the managed world. Are you happy to re-code your algorithm in unmanaged C++ or C? Bringing it into .NET will have the same implications as you were concerned with in your question.

Answer (score 2):

"What is safer in terms to get source code: c++ program without .net libraries or .net obfuscated program." Without .net ofc...

Obfuscated .net .java still easy to decompile. There are pro obfuscators, which makes the code  not recompilable those are slow down the hack process a bit.

Have you have heard if something can be closed that can be opened?
even if is writen is Assembly...

Usually beginner programmers are scared about this kind of theft. I would suggest to first create a software part, which worth to be stolen for others ( not for you )

Comment: Software part is created though.

Comment: *Without .net ofc...* Why? IDA Pro/Hex-Rays can do a dandy job of reversing native binaries to C/C++

Comment: Plus IDA Pro will even be nice enough to draw a little flowchart on the branching structure of your application. How kind :-)

Comment: IDA pro is not a few software. Decompile a .net or .Java app can be done with fre apps, which is easier to get.

Answer (score 2):

Because .NET is designed to be self-descriptive, using an obfuscator will only hinder their progress. Although decompilers will have reduced readability, anyone understanding MSIL will have a better chance. Even C++ applications will be decompilable at some stage, as the program ultimately gets executed step by step in memory. C++ applications will take longer to work it out, but if a hacker knows Assembler (which they probably would if they are decompiling your application to gain access to the algorithm), its just a matter of time.

Obfuscation is really to make it as difficult as possible in a *reasonable* timespan, rather than making it impossible. The same principal lies with encryption. Encryption isn't impossible to break, it just takes so long that the context may not be of any use in 70-80 years time.

There are 2 alternatives I can think of apart from the ones covered here:

- Host the algorithm at a remote location
- Host the algorithm in a hardware component - very very expensive

The first option would be more suited if you have a network connection available. The processing is done on a separate server and the algorithm is not exposed to the public. This is how activation codes work nowadays. A serial code of some sort is generated, encrypted with a public key encryption and sent to a source which will decrypt and validate the data. The response is also encrypted and sent back.

Also, digitally signing your application and your dependencies will also assist as hackers could not plug-in components very easily. If they tried to use a DLL in place of one of your old ones (to fake a call to a service and return "success"), your code would check the digital signature before using the DLL.

So in summary, obfuscating will slow down the process but not prevent it. The only way I can think of is to host that algorithm at a secure location and send requests to it. Yes there is the problem of the hosting scenario, DoS etc, but your algorithm is protected, which is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try something link [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/502283/Strings-Obfuscation-System). However it will only obfuscate the strings. To obfuscate function calls, variables and other elements, look for commercial products and services for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

> How effective are obfuscators?

I find [ConfuserEx](https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx)'s [name](https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/wiki/Name-Protection), [constants](https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/wiki/Constants-Protection), and [control flow](https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/wiki/Control-Flow-Protection) protection quite effective making .NET code difficult to read.

- Using unicode for the `Name protection` can render class/method/etc names into unreadable unicode.
- The `constants protection` encode constant strings like debug log string which provide excellent hints for hacker to guess what the code is doing.
- The `control flow` scramble your code into a lot of switch-cases.

See below for an example of ConfuserEx'ed C# code:

[image]

> What is safer in terms of hiding your algorithms: C++ without .NET libraries or obfuscated .NET programs.

If .NET assembly is not obfuscated, then it's like giving away the source code.

Comparing obfuscated .NET and native x86/x64 code, IMO, the difficulty to read them is about the same. Native x86 code can be disassembled into quite readable C code using software like IDA-Pro. Also there are people who can read and understand x86 language really fast.

> Are there any others way to make .NET source code even more secure?

There is this [Microsoft .NET Native](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dotnetnative.aspx)(still in early stage with limitations) that compiles C# code into native x86/x64 code. This is not actually a protection but just people read x86 code slower.